# How to get content of html page which is modified by javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have the html page which is loaded by cef chronium (for wpf) browser. And its content is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv = "cache-control" content = "max-age=0">
        <meta http-equiv = "cache-control" content = "no-cache, must-revalidate">
        <meta http-equiv = "expires" content = "0">
        <meta http-equiv = "expires" content = "Tue, 01 Jan 1970 1:00:00 GMT">
        <meta http-equiv = "pragma" content = "no-cache">
        <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'><![endif]-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/p2uweb.css" />
        <title></title>
        <script src="working/analitics.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jq.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jq.json.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jq.webforms.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jq.ismbrows.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jq.popups.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jq.cvv.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jq.sbinder1.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jq.hashstring.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/common.js"></script>
        <script src="working/p2uweb.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="switcher"></div>
        <div id="forms"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to parse this page using HtmlAgility.HtmlDocument but I cannot see any controls (except divisions) in body. They all are loaded by some javascript files declared in header. How can I receive full page contents? 
When I open Google Chrome I can press F12 and see all loaded contents. How can I make such things myself?

Comment: use interval timer to check for content ... then cancel interval timer and do what you need

Comment: or subscribe to page load event